# How to get paragraph contents

Tags: paragraphs, parsing

I have been using the following trick to obtain the contents of a paragraph.  It works most of the time, but not on macros like `\lipsum` or `\end{document}` or `\end{minipage}` which expand the `\par` internally.  Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{count}

\def\mypar#1\par{\stepcounter{count}\thecount(#1)\addtocounter{count}{-1}\par}


\begin{document}
\everypar{\mypar}
This is a test.

\lipsum[1]
This is a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image: results]

This also demonstrats that another `\mypar` is executed when `\lipsum` expands inside `\mypar` (recursively).

---

If I convert my application to a macro instead of an environment, the inability to detect the end of the environment is no longer an issue.  In other words, I could just live with it.

I believe I can detect the presence of a `\par` inside a macro by expanding it in a `\savebox` and using `\everypar` to increment a counter.  If I store the input data as a token list, one can add tokens without expanding them.  So it is just a matter of adding tokens one at a time until one expands a `\par`.

Of course, this only works if the macro has a single `\par` at the end.  Macros like `\item` which have a `\par` at the beginning cannot be used with `\parshape` (unless modified).

Comment: Perhaps `\lipsum*[1]`?

Comment: Is this question *specific* to [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum)? Or just a general question about some areas where your `\mypar` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Werner - It also doesn't work on \end{document}, so it's about \mypar.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: For that you might get away with `\AtEndDocument{\par}`.

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in the `shapepar` package.

Comment: @egreg - I have used shapepar before.  Like \parshape it only does single paragraphs and assumes every line is \baelineskip apart.  It only uses vertical lengths to interpolate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to parse the source, I decided to put each paragraph into a separate box.  Also, instead of the whole document I reduced the problem to the contents of an environment (\BODY}.

By putting a `\pagebreak` at the end of each paragraph I can force `\vsplit` to pull off 1 paragraph each time and store the heights.  I repeat the process using normal penalties and these heights.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newcounter{total}
\newcounter{count}
\renewcommand{\thecount}{\Roman{count}}

\NewEnviron{test}{%
  \let\oldpar=\par
  \def\par{\oldpar\pagebreak}%
  \everypar{\stepcounter{total}}%
  \setbox\mybox=\vbox{\BODY}%
  \let\par=\oldpar
  \everypar{\relax}
  \loop\ifnum\value{count}<\value{total}\relax
    \stepcounter{count}%
    \dimen0=\ht\mybox
    \setbox0=\vsplit\mybox to \dimen0
    \advance\dimen0 by -\ht\mybox
    \expandafter\xdef\csname testht\thecount\endcsname{\the\dimen0}%
  \repeat
  \global\setbox\mybox=\vbox{\BODY}%
}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{test}
This is a test.

\lipsum[1]
This is a new paragraph.
\end{test}
\setcounter{count}{0}%
\loop\ifnum\value{count}<\value{total}\relax
  \stepcounter{count}%
  \arabic{count}\par
  \dimen0=\csname testht\thecount\endcsname\relax
  \setbox0=\vsplit\mybox to \dimen0
  \usebox0
\repeat
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `\lipsum*` that does not issue `\par`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{count}

\def\mypar#1\par{\stepcounter{count}\thecount(#1\unskip\unskip)\addtocounter{count}{-1}\par}


\begin{document}
\everypar{\mypar}

This is a test.

\lipsum*[1]

This is a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you were hoping to make `\mypar` into seeing the final `\par` in `\lipsum`, you're out of luck.