# Execute command at every *end* of a paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs

I'd like to execute something at every end of a paragraph (writing sth. to aux file). So I modified `\par` using

```
\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ParHere}%
    \oldpar% original version of \par
}%
```

That works pretty well, *until* a `trivlist`-based environment (`enumerate`, `itemize`, `center`, `quote` etc.) is used, which seems to be magically resetting `\par` to just the original `\par`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\ParHere{}
\let\oldpar\par
\def\par{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ParHere}%
    \oldpar% original version of \par
}
%Attempt for solution which doesn't work:  
%\appto\endtrivlist{%
%   \gdef\par{%
%       \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ParHere}%
%       \oldpar%
%   }%
%}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hallo % Makes \ParHere appearing in aux-file.
\begin{center}
    Centered Text.
\end{center}
More paragraphs 

But not more ParHere entries created in the auxfile. 

asd
\end{document}
```

So it seems `\par` is somehow reset in a `trivlist` environment – fine. But what really gives me headache is: Even if I add

```
\appto\endtrivlist{%
    \gdef\par{%
        \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ParHere}%
        \oldpar%
    }%
}
```

to the preamble, the `\par` command will not be back to normal after the `center` (or any other `trivlist`-based) environment. But if I manually introduce a

```
\makeatletter
\def\par{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\ParHere}%
    \oldpar%
}
\makeatother
```

after `\end{center}`, everything works.

So, why can I not reset `\par` to my custom definition by using `\appto\endtrivlist`? Does anyone have a solution?

PS: I guess it is generally not elegant to redefine `\par` globally? If so, what else could I do? Please note that redefining `\everypar` does not work to me as I really need to execute the aux-file-write at end of a paragraph.

Comment: the `\par` primitive is saved in the macro `\@@par` you can use it.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question, removing my `\let\oldpar\par` and instead using `\@@par`.

Comment: I mean try `\let\oldpar\@@par` and `\def\@@par{....}` i.e. don't use `\par` at all.

Comment: `\par` is redefined in multiple places all over latex, you can only do this in very restricted contexts.  headings, lists, parboxes, floats .... all reset `\par`

Comment: @touhami that wouldn't work (in most places)  a blank line adds the token `\par` not execute the primitive.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you, i was sure it will fail somewhere.

Comment: also not all paragraphs end with `\par` (eg the end of a `\parbox` unless color package is being used)

Comment: @touhami oh well actually if you defined \par and \@@par  it would work in a few more places, but I fear the plan in the question is doomed:-)

Comment: is lualatex a possibility? a lua callback eg `post_linebreak_filter` gets called whenever tex breaks a paragraph into lines so you can write whatever you want to write from Lua at that point.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using XeLaTeX ...

Comment: I think the real question is: Why does the patch of `\endtrivlist` not work but manually redefining `\par` after each `trivlist`-env works?

Comment: Think of this: what should happen at the end of a `trivlist` that is nested inside another list-making environment?  Wouldn’t even the manual redefinition mess everything up anyway, in that case?  To answer the question you ask in your last comment more directly, it is *not* `\endtrivlist` which restores the definition of `\par`, this happens at the *start* of the next paragraph, when `\everypar` is executed.  See the definitions of `\@endparenv` and `\@doendpe` in `ltlists.dtx`, and the definition of `\end` in `ltmiscen.dtx`.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused myself (I should be in my bed by now! :-)  : not at the next execution of `\everypar`, but as part of the `\end` command; in any case, *after* `\endtrivlist` has already completed execution.

Comment: I don't see how anybody can say what else you could do without knowing what you are trying to do.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296584/how-to-get-paragraph-contents?s=1|0.0817

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first question, “Why can I not reset `\par` to my custom definition by using `\appto\endtrivlist`?”, is pretty easy to answer, but your second one, where you ask for advice on what to do instead, requires that you specify in greater detail what you want to achieve—and please note that this is only a necessary, but not sufficient condition. (:-)

Let’s look in detail at what happens when you execute, say,

```
\end{center}
```

The first thing that the TeX compiler actually does is to expand the `\end` macro, which is defined in the LaTeX kernel as follows:

```
\def\end#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
```

(see the file `latex.ltx`, lines 4157–4160; but note that the version of this file which is installed on the computer I’m currently writing on is 2017/01/01, patch level 1: I’m not sure that it is the latest release).  So, the next step is to execute

```
\csname endcenter\endcsname
```

that is, `\endcenter`; this is defined on line 4171:

```
\def\endcenter{\endtrivlist}
```

OK, at this point `\endtrivlist` is executed, and let us suppose that it contains your custom addition that resets the meaning of `\par`.  But there is still more code awaiting to be executed as part of the expansion of `\end{center}`.  The next piece is

```
\@checkend{center}
```

which is the macro that checks that `\begin` and `\end` declarations are correctly paired, and which plays no rôle in our present discussion.  Then comes

```
\expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
```

This construct expands the `\if@endpe` conditional *before* ending the current group (which is the group that was started by `\begin{center}`): what’s this?  Well, if you look at the definition of `\endtrivlist` (which, in my version of `latex.ltx`, begins on line 4616), you’ll see that one of the last things that gets executed is the `\@endparenv` macro (the `@noparlist` switch is certainly false in our context—provided that your `center` environment is not empty—I must ask you to trust me about this, because I cannot explain all the details); this macro is defined immediately below, at lines 4638–4639:

```
\def\@endparenv{%
  \addpenalty\@endparpenalty\addvspace\@topsepadd\@endpetrue}
```

You can see that the `@endpe` switch is set true as the last thing.

Let’s now return to our

```
\expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
```

So, we’ve just seen that the `@endpe` switch has just been set true as part of the execution of `\endtrivlist`, and—notice this—we are now checking its value *before* ending the group, so we do find that it is still true.  At this point, the following tokens are still awaiting execution:

```
\engroup \@doendpe \fi \if@ignore \@ignorefalse \ignorespaces \fi
```

with a true conditional pending.  So, the next thing that happens is that the current group is ended (note that this undoes your custom resetting of the meaning of `\par`, but this is not yet the explanation, because, at this point, you would expect `\par` to resume the meaning it had before the beginning of the `center` environment).  Then `\@doendpe` is executed.

And *here* lies the explanation.

Indeed, `\@doendpe` is defined as follows (lines 4640–4645, that is, immediately below the definition of `\@endparenv` that we saw a minute ago):

```
\def\@doendpe{\@endpetrue
     \def\par{\@restorepar
              \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
              \everypar{}\par\@endpefalse}\everypar
               {{\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
                \everypar{}\@endpefalse}}
```

We see that, when `\@doendpe` is executed, `\par` is redefined again.

---

That should suffice, for now.  Of course, much more insight is needed to decide what to do next, and even to judge whether there is still some hope of pursuing your intent of figuring out an acceptable way of redefining `\par` that is, at the same time, sufficiently robust to survive all the twists and turns that this control sequence undergoes in the LaTeX kernel, and not only there.  In case you are now thinking of moving your patch from `\endtrivlist` to `\@doendpe`, bear in mind that this macro sets the definition of `\par` that it sets for a very good reason, so you cannot simply overwrite it with your own.  I regret to say that, like D.C., I lean toward seeing your idea as doomed to failure.

If I may, I’d like to conclude by suggesting a couple of questions that you should ask to yourself:

1. What should happen to paragraphs contained in lists?
   Should they be treated in the same way as, or differently from,
   the other ones?
2. Same question as 1, for paragraphs that constitute sectional headings.

(Deep breath.)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo for that explanation which helped me understand why patching `\endtrivlist` didn't work!

Comment: To answer the question what I actually want to achieve: I'd like to test whether a paragraph gets interrupted by a float. So my idea was to make `\everypar`, `\par`, and the `float` environment write stuff to the AUX file (using a counter for pars), then I can identify if a paragraph is interrupted by a float. With this I intend to write a solution to this problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/is-there-a-general-command-to-disable-indentation-of-paragraphs-after-figures-an (removing \noindent of new pars after floats). I have a solution now and will post it after testing period.

Comment: @LaTechneuse: The question that you cite in your comments makes, in my not-so-humble opinion, no sense at all: there is no notion, in LaTeX, of “a paragraph that comes after a float”.  Even if a paragraph follows a floating environment in the source file, this doesn’t have any relation with their mutual positioning in the printout; the float could end up to the top, or bottom, of the current page, or just as well on some of the following ones, perhaps also on a page by itself.

Comment: Of course. This is why the problem is about detecting the positioning in the *printout* not in the source code. Otherwise it would be very easy. From the perspective of the printed result, the problem is simple: My publishing company requests that new paragraphs after floating figures in the printout be started without indentation, while other new paragraphs do have indentation. There is no LaTeX mechanism to implement this and the whole LaTeX community is rather pessimistic about the possibility of solving this problem. (But I have a solution now, I will share it soon.)

Comment: @LaTechneuse: This looks like a task for the `savepos` module of the `zref` package (but mine is only a vague idea).

Comment: @GuM I bountied a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516678/color-coding-a-dialogue-alternate-paragraphs-in-different-tcolorboxes). By now, I have narrowed it down to one question: _How do I, within a self-defined environment which will contain nothing but plain text, have a custom command executed between any two paragraphs?_ It is my hope that your insight might come in useful there...