# block each line in the beginning and end

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to insert hyphens before each paragraph?

What about after the paragraph?

Like this:

```
----Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing ...
[...]
... fames ac turpis egestas.----------------------------
```

I tried using `\dotfill`, but I'd like not to have to do that manually. And I'd like to have hyphens, not dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just for plain paragraphs (no lists).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{blockpars}
 {\everypar{{\setbox0=\lastbox\hyphens{\wd0}}}%
  \let\par\hyphenpar
}
 {\hyphenpar}

\newcommand{\hyphens}[1]{\xleaders\hbox{-}\hskip#1}
\newcommand{\hyphenpar}{\unskip\hyphens{\fill}\kern0pt\endgraf}

\begin{document}

\begin{blockpars}
This is a blocked paragraph.

This is another blocked paragraph, which is longer and
wraps to the next line, provided we add a proper amount
of words.

\lipsum[1-2]\lipsum*[3]
\end{blockpars}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked as expected. Great!
Now I'll just have to figure out what all of that means, but that's a job I'll do with most pleasure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\def\mypar#1\par{\MyDashes#1\MyDashes\par}
\let\oldep\everypar  \newtoks\everypar  \oldep{\the\everypar\mypar}
```

which is adapted from:

- [How to get paragraph contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296584/4301)
- [Why does \everypar not work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119760/4301)

[image]

### Notes:

- This is *only* tested for paragraphs. In list environments it seems to add the hypens to beginning of each `\item`.

  [image]

  Not sure what other difficulties this solution will have.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\MyDashes}{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries-- -- --}}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296584/4301
\def\mypar#1\par{\MyDashes#1\MyDashes\par}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119760/4301
\let\oldep\everypar  \newtoks\everypar  \oldep{\the\everypar\mypar}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed tellus sapien, ultrices non dapibus quis, suscipit nec tortor. Suspendisse ultrices scelerisque purus ac fermentum. Cras laoreet quam at dolor vehicula, hendrerit pharetra tellus rhoncus. Maecenas tincidunt, eros et bibendum rutrum, ex magna porta sem, ac tempus elit arcu vel leo. In tristique ligula non augue eleifend ornare. Integer pellentesque massa ligula, quis facilisis metus pellentesque a. Proin non massa libero. Praesent ut dolor non erat ornare elementum. Etiam pellentesque metus justo, vel fringilla mi condimentum sed.

In nec est sapien. Maecenas blandit laoreet neque a convallis. Proin dapibus nisi felis, id feugiat nunc cursus eget. Maecenas libero lorem, fringilla eu hendrerit non, volutpat a urna. Duis elementum facilisis quam, at euismod nulla tincidunt eu. Curabitur vitae dui nec nibh elementum blandit vel finibus massa. Sed mollis lorem vel diam molestie aliquet. Maecenas scelerisque augue sit amet urna gravida vulputate.

Quisque tincidunt ac mi in gravida. Phasellus eleifend, metus at dignissim porttitor, ex tellus venenatis justo, et gravida purus nisi at lectus. Sed id felis in urna lobortis ultrices eu eu risus. Ut condimentum arcu eu ante dignissim, a vestibulum tellus sodales. Fusce mauris nisi, faucibus sed convallis at, molestie eget quam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi et fringilla tortor, id scelerisque arcu. Maecenas vitae ipsum nisi. Mauris non maximus massa, eget rhoncus felis. Nullam nec metus venenatis est vehicula feugiat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam congue, urna cursus mollis venenatis, libero risus rutrum tellus, et ornare elit magna eget felis. Proin a metus arcu.

Proin lorem libero, elementum sit amet mollis quis, eleifend a nisi. Donec sit amet vehicula orci. Pellentesque sed aliquet ligula. Proin non dignissim diam. Aenean mi purus, interdum et dui nec, pretium faucibus mauris. Ut pulvinar mollis eros. Sed eleifend non quam vitae volutpat.

Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum sed consequat quam, eu dictum tortor. Nulla nec leo eleifend, congue nunc eget, venenatis nibh. Nam molestie turpis ante, et facilisis libero ultricies a. Morbi et bibendum metus. Aliquam sollicitudin placerat viverra. Vestibulum eu luctus magna. Curabitur eu faucibus mauris, ut ultricies metus. Fusce magna metus, mollis at consequat at, congue sit amet nibh. Duis vitae massa sit amet eros accumsan posuere sed vitae sem. Quisque nec nisl purus.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer simpler solutions like this one, but this one in particular does not seem to work as well since the final hyphens don't go til the end of line as in egreg's solution. Thank you anyway.